# I had created folder in the root directory of laravel on level of app but cannot get the laravel session in that folder files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

1. app
2. config
3. bootstrap
4. resources
5. new folder

As you can see the level of my new folder is at the root level. The issue is how can I get all the Laravel functionality like helper function and session.

I had created a file called **index.php** inside my new folder and try to get the helper function and some session value in this index file in which I am using some core PHP functions which are working properly but can't get anything from the Laravel function.

Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: What are your errors ? Have you added the `namespace` (PSR) to `composer` file ?